# Python type hints to match different class, with common behavior

Tags: python, type-hinting

Hello everyone I'm looking for the 
best way to type hinting my function where I want to accept different types of class, but with common behavior. 
example:

```
class HumanPlayer:
    pass

class IAPlayer:
    pass

def play_game(player1, player2)
    pass
```

How can I add type hints for `player1` and `player2` that can support the both kinds of players?
Of course I can use `object` or create a parent class `Player`. But I'm sure that this are not the right solucion.

Comment: Either you *have* a definition of an interface, e.g. a shared parent class or an [`ABC`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html), or you hint against `Union[HumanPlayer, IAPlayer]`…!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straight forward answer would be to use `typing.Union` and hint against:

```
Union[HumanPlayer, IAPlayer]
```

However, this means that the passed object may have *any* traits of *either* class. As long as both classes implement the same interface, that doesn't really matter. But it's hard to keep both classes in sync just by convention, so you should think about a formal way to help that process by using a shared parent class. An [`ABC`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) is very useful in this regard:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Player(ABC):
    def something_common(self):
        # do something common

    @abstractmethod
    def play(self):
        """Players must implement their specific play style."""
        raise NotImplementedError

    ...

class HumanPlayer(Player):
    def play(self):
        # play humanely

    def care_for_bodily_needs(self):
        # take a break
```

Now you can safely hint against `Player` and its well defined interface. If `HumanPlayer` or `IAPlayer` implement something the other doesn't, that won't be included in the `Player` interface and thus cannot safely be used inside your function `play_game`, making your code type safe.

```
def play_game(player1: Player, player2: Player):
    player1.something_common()
    player1.play()
    player2.play()

def ensure_is_comfortable(player: HumanPlayer):
    player.care_for_bodily_needs()  # only safe to call here
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to add a common ancestor for both classes, and use it as the type hint:

```
class PlayerMixin:
    pass

class HumanPlayer(PlayerMixin):
    pass

class AIPlayer(PlayerMixin):
    pass

def play_game(player1: PlayerMixin, player2: PlayerMixin)
    pass
```

Comment: If you're *just* using it for a shared type hint, and you're not going to add anything to `PlayerMixin`, it would be much better defined as `Player = Union[HumanPlayer, AIPlayer]`. Imposing an unused hierarchy is pointless and just potentially confusing. If `Player` doesn't define any methods or attributes, then what are you hinting against and what is type-safe to use…?

Comment: That's a good question, but it feels like a completely different question and with the bare bones example I cant really tell what are you planning to have in the classes, so it's probably up to you to answer that yourself. You could use `Protocol` ( https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocols.html ) for the mixin as `class PlayerMixin(Protocol):` for further type checking there, but the answer I gave is as much as I could extrapolate from your example.